# Resteasy returns 404

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs

I'm totally new to Resteasy and still learning how it works.
But I cannot work this code out.

I start the tomcat server and it should return fake users information, but somehow gets 404. (No error shown to Eclipse.) I already googled to figure out why this code doesn't work but I couldn't.

To get all users, the URI should be `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users`

```
package com.demo.sprintSample.config;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class ResteasyConfig extends Application {


}
```

```
package com.demo.sprintSample.resource;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

import com.demo.sprintSample.model.User;
import com.demo.sprintSample.service.UserService;

@Component
@Path("/api/v1/users")
public class UserResourceResteasy {

    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UserResourceResteasy(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userService.getAllUsers();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{userUid}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response fetchUser(@PathParam("userUid") UUID userUid) {
        Optional<User> userOptional = userService.getUser(userUid);
        if(userOptional.isPresent()) {
            return Response.ok(userOptional.get()).build();
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity(new ErrorMessage("user"+userUid+"was not found."))
                .build();
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response insertNewUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        UUID uid = UUID.randomUUID();
        int result = userService.insertUser(user);
        return getIntegerResponseEntity(result);
    }


    @PUT
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response updateUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        int result = userService.updateUser(user);
        return getIntegerResponseEntity(result);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{userUid}")
    public Response deleteUser(@PathParam("userUid") UUID userUid) {
        int result =userService.removeUser(userUid);
        return getIntegerResponseEntity(result);
    }

    private Response getIntegerResponseEntity(int result) {
        if(result == 1) {
            return Response.ok().build();
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sprintSample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sprintSample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <rest.easy.client.version>4.5.6.Final</rest.easy.client.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>29.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
               <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
           </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
              <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
              <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
          </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: What does your web.xml contain?

Comment: Check this doc out: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.0.GA/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html

Comment: You need to add `resteasy-servlet-initializer` dependency. As an aside, your pom looks crazy. You have so much random stuff, enough to run three different frameworks.